# Script every AD user on every DC

Tags: powershell, active-directory, domaincontroller

I am beginner in scripting with powershell. My boss asked me to create a script that will get information about the last logon from every user in our domain on every DC. I have created the following script:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

function Get-ADUsersLastLogon() {
    $dcs = Get-ADDomainController -Filter { Name -like "*" }
    $users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties LastLogonDate | Where-Object { $_.LastLogonDate -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-30) }
    $time = 0
    $exportFilePath = "C:\output\aduser.csv"
    $columns = "name,username,datetime,domain controller,enabled"

    Out-File -filepath $exportFilePath -force -InputObject $columns

    foreach ($user in $users) {
        $Activeuser = $user.Enabled

        foreach ($dc in $dcs) { 
            $hostname = $dc.HostName
            $currentUser = Get-ADUser $user.SamAccountName | Get-ADObject -Server $hostname -Properties lastLogon
    
            if ($currentUser.LastLogon -gt $time) {
                $time = $currentUser.LastLogon
            }
        }

        $dt = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($time)
        $row = $user.Name + "," + $user.SamAccountName + "," + $dt + "," + $hostname + "," + $Activeuser
    
        Out-File -filepath $exportFilePath -append -noclobber -InputObject $row
    
        $time = 0
    }
}

Get-ADUsersLastLogon
```

My boss asked me to change the following things in this script:

- the output of the domain controller is only our DC in an other country. I want to know which DC the user last logged into.
- The running of the script is taking too long. Like half a day. Is it possible to make this faster?

I hope someone can help me with this, I tried a few things, but I didn't work :(

Comment: there isnt much room for improvement in your script tbh, the only corrections it needs is the way you're exporting the data and the line on `$currentUser` doesn't require `Get-ADObject`... aside from that if you want to make this faster it will require multithreading

Comment: And this `$_.LastLogonDate -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)` could be done with AD filter

Answer (score 2):

> the output of the domain controller is only our DC in an other country. I want to know which DC the user last logged into.

It looks like you've already solved this by querying each DC for each user object.

> The running of the script is taking too long. Like half a day. Is it possible to make this faster?

That's because you're querying each DC for each user object :)

One way of speeding it up would be to flip your query logic around - query each DC for *all the users* but only *once*, and then update the logon timestamps only when a newer one is encountered.
For that to work, you need to keep track of the highest timestamp seen for each user. I'd suggest using a simple hashtable to index the user accounts by their user name:

```
$dcs = Get-ADDomainController -Filter { Name -like "*" }

# create hashtable to keep track of latest timestamps per user
$userLastLogonTable = @{}

foreach($dc in $dcs){
  # fetch all users from each DC
  Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties LastLogonDate -Server $dc | ForEach-Object {
    # Only add new timestamps to table if we either haven't seen the username before, or if the timestamp is newer than the current
    if(-not $userLastLogonTable.Contains($_.SAMAccountName) -or $userLastLogonTable[$_.SAMAccountName].LastLogonDate -lt $_.LastLogonDate){
      $userLastLogonTable[$_.SAMAccountName] = [pscustomobject]@{
        LastLogonDate = $_.LastLogonDate
        LogonServer   = $dc.Name
      }
    }
  }
}

# Now that we have a complete table of all users and their last logon timestamp, 
# we can then easily identify usernames that have no recent logons
$staleUserNames = $userLastLogonTable.PSBase.Keys |Where-Object { $userLastLogonTable[$_].LastLogonDate -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-30) }
```

`$staleUserNames` now contain the user names of all user accounts that have not logged in for 30 days of more.

Comment: Can you provide me with the full script, so that I can test if this is the right solution?

Comment: @arjunajankie I'm not sure I understand your question. Did you try executing the code in my answer? Remove `$staleUserNames =` to make it print the output to the console instead of storing it in that variable

Comment: I tried somethins, but I don't think I understand the script totally. I see that there are some users were printed in the terminal. Can you add the following things in the script:

-the last DC the users logged into
-If the user account is enabled
-The user name itself.

If this information can be exported to csv, it would be nice.

Already thnx for the help

Comment: @arjunajankie Sure, done. To export, simply do `$staleUserNames |Export-Csv -Path path\to\output.csv -NoTypeInformation`

Comment: thank you for trying, but I doesn't work entirly, when I am the script. I see a .csv with length and a bunch of numbers. Can you troubleshoot this for me please. I tried some stuff but it didn't work.

I did this to the last 2 rows:
$staleUserNames = $userLastLogonTable.PSBase.Keys |Where-Object { $userLastLogonTable[$_].LastLogonDate -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-30) }
$staleUserNames |Export-Csv -Path $path -NoTypeInformation

Comment: @arjunajankie A single `Length` column is a symptom that you've attempted to export a list of raw string values (as opposed to a list of objects). It sounds like you've updated the last line of the script, but not the rest - please make sure you run the latest version of the code above.

Comment: I used the latest script, but still no change. The output is the single Length column.